# Javascript: Having trouble with .map() on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dictionary

This code runs great on Chrome, FFX, etc. It takes the content of a textarea and separates all lines in different array items (new lines are represented by empty array items). When testing it on IE, it throws an error. Code:

This is tregex's value and the call:

```
var tregex = /\n|([^\r\n.!?]+([.!?]+|$))/gim;

var source = $('#text').val().match(tregex).map($.trim);
```

The code throws this error message because of **.map()** (IE only)

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729) Timestamp: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 21:52:48 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 128
>   Char: 6 Code: 0 URI: http://mydomain.com/src/common.js

Why? Any way I can support it on IE7+? (this was tested on IE8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is a terrible browser, and as such doesn't have a built-in map function (at least not in IE7-8).  Since you're trying to call map on the results of a Regular Expression match (as opposed to calling it on a jQuery results object), the only map you can use is the built-in one (that IE doesn't have).

There are many libraries that simulate map for you however, including jQuery, Underscore, and Mochikit.

Here's an example of how you could use jQuery's to do what you're trying to do:

```
$.map($('#text').val().match(tregex), $.trim);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code may be working in FF and Chrome by accident.  Did you mean to use `jQuery.map`?  You are using `Array.map` which isn't supported in IE prior to 9.

Consider the following as a replacement.

```
var source = $.map($('#text').val().match(tregex), $.trim);
```

This uses jQuery's map implementation to loop through and do the trim.

Comment: Same solution as @machineghost's - i accepted his answer first. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: May you please tell my how can I do that in this case? https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/6/

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure `Array.map()` was only added in IE9. You should loop through the array manually instead.

Comment: It's far easier to include the shims he should have included in the first place than to rewrite all code to use hand written loops. **Especially** since the OP asked if there is a way to add the support.

Comment: You are correct it was not added until IE 9. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679976(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Instead of looping manually I chosed @machineghost 's solution that makes use of jQuery's map simulation. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the support just by including the [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for it:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {
  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if ({}.toString.call(callback) != "[object Function]") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (thisArg) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) where Array is
    // the standard built-in constructor with that name and len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while(k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[ k ];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal method of callback
        // with T as the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor {Value: mappedValue, Writable: true, Enumerable: true, Configurable: true},
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, Pk, { value: mappedValue, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[ k ] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };      
}
```

You can also include the [es5shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/) which adds `.map` and all the other missing array methods in IE7-8 plus other goods like `Function#bind`

Comment: Since he's using jQuery, he already has a shim loaded: `$.map(source, callback)`

Comment: @BrianNickel it has different signature than [].map and would require rewrite of code. Though in this case I guess the rewrite would be acceptable since it's just in one place.

Comment: It's a trivial rewrite, especially considering he's using it on a jQuery specific callback.  If you're already using a heavy library that implements a function, there's no real reason to break from it and add duplicate functionality.

Comment: @BrianNickel you have a point there for his case but in general I recommend the shim since it has consistent and standard behavior, such as accepting a context argument. In jQuery each, index is the first argument to callback, where as in jQuery map, the index is the second argument.

Comment: There are pros and cons to both approaches, but it's worth pointing out that one con of the "shim" approach is that it extends a core JS object.  For a more thorough explanation of the flaws of that approach, you may want to read: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Comment: @machineghost I don't understand, that link says that extending native objects when shimming standard behavior, is fine.

Comment: Ok, A) there is no possible way you could have read that entire article (and the many sub-links that were key to it) in the three minutes between when I posted and when you responded.  B) Had you read it, you would have gotten a much more complex understanding than just "it is/isn't ok to shim".

Comment: Again, there are pros/cons to either approach, and I'm not advocating one way or the other.  What I am advocating is that the OP (and anyone reading this later) understand what the pros/cons are, and that link I provided should be helpful for anyone wanting to do that.

Comment: @machineghost You'd probably want to reference the parts where it says it's not fine, because he is pretty much giving the green light for it. He even says he is himself extending native objects in his library when the methods are spec-compliant. Maybe you are thinking non-standard extensions or extending host objects which is not the case here.

Comment: It takes a *pretty* lazy person to pretend to read an article in 3 minutes, then come back and claim to have read it, THEN to try and get someone else to read it for them and highlight the parts that interest them.  That being said, we programmers (myself included) are a lazy lot, so I'll humor you: find the section titled "Downsides", where the author writes "Are there any downsides?" and then goes on to explain them.

Comment: @machineghost I didn't read the article in 3 minutes but my conclusion is same after now fully reading it. The downsides don't really apply here. The op is not relying on nonstandard behavior, the second point only really applies to stuff like Netscape Navigator 2, and the third point doesn't apply for `.map` since it's perfectly shimmable.

Comment: It's great that you've decided that the downsides don't apply to you :-) (not a big surprise though, given your posts so far).  The thing is though, your opinion is completely irrelevant (as is mine, for that matter).  The opinion that does matter is the OP's, as neither of us can truly say what downsides do/don't apply to them.  So (again) the only way the OP can properly decide is to to get informed, and that's why I recommended the article.

Comment: @machineghost The points 2 and 3 are not dependent on OP but what is being shimmed and where. We are talking IE7 and 8, not IE3 or NS2.